# Filter items either or in directus

Tags: directus

I'm playing around with Directus and wanted to filter my items.
I would like to receive all messages that either I am as sender or I am as receiver.

my get / messages looks like this

```
[
    {
        "content": "Hey!",
        "id": "1",
        "receiver": "1",
        "sender": "2"
    },
    {
        "content": "hello",
        "id": "2",
        "receiver": "2",
        "sender": "1"
    }
]
```

My backend request url looks like this

```
/items/messages?filter[sender]=${user_id}&filter[receiver]=${user_id}
```

But it is not working :( so please help me to get it done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/items/messages?filter={"_or":[{"sender":{"_eq": "id"}},{"receiver":{"_eq":"id"}}]}
```

Expanded version:

```json
"_or": [
    {
        "sender": {
            "_eq": "id"
        }
    },
    {
        "reveiver": {
            "_eq": "id"
        }
    }
]
```

Visit the [official docs](https://docs.directus.io/reference/filter-rules.html#logical-operators) to read more about filtering rules and logical operators.